# Why Bootstrap theme doesn't been uploaded with https module on nodejs?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I created a web interface page using bootstrap and nodejs.When I use http module,my interface appears very well in the browser but when I opened it using https,the theme doesn't appears like other(the navbar doesn't appear and so many other functionalities).
I used these links for bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I used also :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Into the browser console I got these errors:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://192.168.43.155:4000/signin' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.



[blocked] The page at 'https://192.168.43.155:4000/signin' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [http content on a https page - Mixed content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554775/http-content-on-a-https-page-mixed-content)

Comment: It's not duplicate. Author of the other question was aware that puting content from `http` address to `https` site causes problem and was searching for workaround. Alexo Rocco here have no idea that he can't mix it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into your browser console if it reports any errors. You are probably attaching scripts and styles from `http` cdn on `https` site therefore your browser is blocking it as it violates security.

Instead of `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/...` use `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/...` as source of bootstrap scripts and styles. It will then work on both 'http' and 'https' sites.

Comment: I changed it but no vain.

Comment: You still have `http` links to bootstrap content. Looks like you did not restarted your app after changing the urls. Restart your app and check again.

Comment: I restart it but I got the same error,the browser didn't use the https .

Comment: Click on `View page source` and make sure you have correct links in your content includes.

Answer (score 1):

So, your issue consist on the files not being safe to pull when you have a https call, all the links should be secured when your website is running HTTPS.

So, a simple solution for CDN related links, its to simply remove the http: and all the links by default will use what the client website uses by default.

So:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you check, your source code if you have any css files? or if your code gets updated in the front-end?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer, here is what I found out. 
I just had the same issue. The way I solved it was that I found all external links starting with `http://` and replaced it just with `//`. For instance, `http://bootstrap.com/.../` changed to `//bootstrap.com/.../`. This way it will choose depending on a connection, which protocol to apply.

Hope this helps.