# Mathjax don't show up on Jekyll Github Pages but show up on localhost

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, mathjax, kramdown

I am using Jekyll on my Github Page. I created a blog post using MathJax to display math equations.

I used the script written in [here](http://georg.io/2013/11/how-this-page-was-made/) in a file `mathjax_support.html` that I put in my `_includes`directory. Then in `_includes/head.html` I added the line

```
{% include mathjax_support.html %}
```

just before the `</head>`.

Once I do that, running my Jekyll blog locally on localhost works just fine but commiting to my Github Page will break the MathJax code.

[Here is the blog post](https://rivten.github.io/2016/11/05/surface_simplification.html) on Github that I am trying to display correctly. I am using kramdown as my markdown parser.

I cannot understand why it works on one side and not the other.

If anyone has any idea, I would be happy to hear it. Thanks !

Comment: The site is using https, it won't load MathJax from an insecure http connection. A quick look into your browsers console would easily have shown you this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http content on a https page - Mixed content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554775/http-content-on-a-https-page-mixed-content)

Answer (score -4):

You don't really need to get MathJax working on your GitHub Page. You can instead implement this hack:

- **Step 1)** Run the blog locally and take screenshots of all expressions
- **Step 2)** Commit the screenshots to your GH Page or upload them to an image hosting service
- **Step 3)** Replace all expressions with their respective images, e.g replace `$x+2=3$` with [image: $x+2=3$ rendered in MathJax]. **Use direct links or browsers will be unable to load the images!**

  Btw, this is the Markdown syntax for inline images: `![description of the image, in case it doesn't get loaded](link-to-the-image "mouseover text (optional)")`
- **Step 4)** That's it! Now you can commit everything to the GH Page and have it work just fine.

Comment: There are some good reasons to use mathjax. E.g. You don't need to do new screenshots if you make corrections, you get highres formulas, can get explanations etc