# Do I need to change PHP form submit and MySQL insterter code when installing an SSL certificate on the server?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, encryption

I hope you are fine today.

I have a question that I couldn't find a definite answer to. Most of the resources lead me to believe that the question is moot and I don't need to worry, but I am not sure, unfortunately.

I have a simple site, nothing too complex. On that site there is a form where users can submit data that is saved to **MySQL** database using simple **PHP** functions. Data is submitted by **POST**, sanitized and then sent to localhost database to be inserted into the table using mysqli() and prepared statements.

Now to the point. Everything works just fine now, but the data may be private so I want to use an SSL certificate (hosting provider also sells the certificates so the installation itself is a 1-click affair)

**Question: Do I need to modify my code for SSL compatibility?**

I never did that before, so are there any things in my simple case that I should consider and learn about?

I know that the inserting function itself probably doesn't need any modifications because it's connecting to the database that is on the same host as the back-end, but the form POST is after all coming from the outside user, so should I worry about that?

And a broader question: in case of a simple site like mine (just some regular HTML, CSS, PHP as shown, some vanilla JS and jQuery for front-end styling purposes and for Google Analytics and Tag Manager) what else should I consider when switching to SSL, **aside from reconfiguring htaccess to force viewers to use HTTPS and making sure there is no mixed content?**

Everything I read leads me to believe that once the hosting providers installs the certificate I should be able to just type `https://example.com` and that's it, everything should work fine.

Is it true?

Sorry if the question is lame, but I couldn't find the definite answer - I don't understand things sometimes. Thanks for any answer in advance.

Here is some of my code, just in case.

**Index.php and form:**

```
<?php

// Nonce (not mentioned in the question, but I didn't want to omit it for clarity)
$timestamp = time();
$form_action = 'submit_form';
$nonce = create_nonce($form_action, $timestamp);

// Pushing data 
if(isset($_POST['form1'])){
    if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) { 
        $insert = process_data($_POST);
    }
}

?>

// The Form

<form action="" method="post">

// Nonce fields, ignore
    <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="<?php echo $timestamp; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_action" value="<?php echo $form_action; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo $nonce; ?>">

// Here is the rest of the form
    <input type="text" name="stuff1" required>
    <input type="text" name="stuff2" required>
    <input type="text" name="stuff3" required>
    <input type="text" name="stuff4" required>
    <input type="text" name="stuff5" required>
    <button type="submit" name="form1">SEND STUFF</button>
</form>
```

**The functions themselves:**

```
// NONCE - Creating the nonce
if ( ! function_exists( 'create_nonce' ) ) {
    function create_nonce($action, $time) {
        $str = sprintf('%s_%s_%s', $action, $time, NONCE_SALT1);
        $nonce = hash('sha512', $str);

        return $nonce;
    }
}

// NONCE - Verification
if ( ! function_exists( 'verify_nonce' ) ) {
    function verify_nonce($nonce, $action, $time) {
        $check = create_nonce($action, $time);

        if ( $nonce == $check ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}


// Now the important bit: the function processing data from the form
if ( ! function_exists( 'process_data' ) ) {
    function process_data($post) {
        // Check nonce
        $verify = verify_nonce($post['nonce'], $post['form_action'], $post['timestamp']);

        if ( false === $verify ) {
            return false;
        }

        // Sanitization
        $args = array(
            'stuff1' => 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING',
            'stuff2' => 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING',
            'stuff3' => 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING',
            'stuff4' => 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING',
            'stuff5' => 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING',
        );

        $filter_post = filter_var_array($post, $args);


        // Insert into the database
        $mysql = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        $stmt = $mysql->prepare("
            INSERT INTO mydatatable (stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,stuff4,stuff5) 
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
        ");

        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", 
            $filter_post['stuff1'], $filter_post['stuff2'], $filter_post['stuff3'], $filter_post['stuff4'], $filter_post['stuff5']
        );

        $insert = $stmt->execute();

        // Closing connections

        $stmt->close();
        $mysql->close();

        return $insert;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, but if you have actual full links that load images , you need to change them .and add https://url/image_file

Comment: I feel kind of bad answering a question that you've obviously put a lot of effort into with just "No." but I believe that's the answer.

Comment: The only thing you likely need to worry about is if you have any links or form actions that point explicitly to `http://` URLs.

Comment: what you need to keep in mind is to not mix `http` and `https` together. Look into using  protocol-less Urls. Edit: as described in this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/10554775/1415724

Comment: I concur with everyone else. Shouldn't be an issue, certainly not based on the code you included in your question. Just flagging a possible typo in the above code however: `$filter_post['stuff2]` is missing a closing single-quote. Just make sure your source code doesn't have that :)

Comment: @DarraghEnright: There is no typo in the site code, I removed the single-quote accidentally when writing the question :) I fixed it anyway, thank you.

Comment: Everyone: thanks for your comments! I am pretty confident in what I need to do now. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the SSL certificate, your website must handle data using the URL with HTTPS. I suggest that the form method be post really, due to the proposed use of SSL, since the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute will not make much difference when the page is already loaded using HTTPS.

When sending data from an open page with HTTPS from the browser (client-side) to a URL (included in the action attribute) being a PHP like you did, the browser will send the encrypted information to the hosting server. In turn PHP will receive this clean data for manipulation. As far as server-level data security is concerned, I believe that it is sufficient to review the URL parameterization and it is possible to include this in the htaccess file, as is the case with the URL with www and non-www, both HTTPS URLs must work, including returning the 404 code (if not found) or 301 (redirect) see more information in https://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php